# Facet blocks are not shown with Facet API Pretty Paths activate

Tags: search

I've enabled Facet API Pretty Paths and the Face blocks are not shown once I select a category.

For example: the Facet Blocks (color and prices) are not shown for the link: /products/field_brand/simple-threads-68

These are:
Drupal 7.44
Facet API Pretty Paths: 7x-1.4
Profile: Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.38)

Thanks,
Araujo

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I got the 'error'

The Facet blocks are visible for the URL: products
When you install Face Pretty Paths, the URL is modified including the segment of the search result.
I just added the "products/*" to the visibility of the block.

Show block on specific pages -> Only the listed pages: products/*